# Jmeter sharepoint login issues

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, jmeter, httprequest

i'm using Jmeter to perform some tests on a website with the login in sharepoint.
The problem i'm facing is about the login: it has to be performed by the chrome mask (photo attached).

[image]

If i do it manually, obviously no problem.

If i try it by jmeter i obtain always error401.

In order to perform it, i've tried by using the jmeter recorder, but it doesn't perform the login because of the proxy.

So i've tried with the chrome plugin and it has correctly recorded everithing, giving me a get request only and adding to my plan an HTTP Authorization Manager with:
BASEURL: my_link
USERNAME: MyDomain\MyUsername
PASSWORD: MyPassword
DOMAIN is empty
REALM is empty
MECHANISM: basic

[image]

So, trying to launch the only get that i have, with the following header manager:
[image]

it always gives me error 401:
[image]

I've also tried by moving the domain from the username tab to Domain and removed the date header from the header manager of the get.

I've also seen that the recording from blazemeter plugin gives to me a get with an header manager with the field "authorization" compiled with "Basic and the key calculated starting from username and password" and is a Basic type.

But if i remove that authentication header and launch again, the requestheaders doesn't contain anymore a basic authorization (with the relative code) but a NTLM request with a bigger code.
What i'm doing wrong? How can i perform correctly the login?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change "Mechanism" to `BASIC_DIGEST` for [NTLM authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) (if you're sure that it's really NTLM)

However it is better to inspect request and response headers, it will allow you to identify which authentication protocol is being used under the hood.

For NTLM you need to supply: username (without domain), password, domain and mechanism (`BASIC_DIGEST`)

If it is [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) - you need to choose `KERBEROS` mechanism, specify the [realm](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2015/10/21/domain-to-kerberos-realm-mapping/)  and perform the appropriate configuration in `jaas.conf` and `krb5.conf` files (both live in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. Do you know how can i understand exactly wich is the proper mechanism?